# SHA2 certificate and TLS cipher suites compatablity

Tags: tls, certificates

I have a server which is configured to use TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2. The server is configured with a certificate siged by SHA-512. The server supports only these cipher suites:

```
• TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
• TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
• TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
• TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
• TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
• TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

The client (browser) requested for the handshake and offer these cipher suites:

```
• TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
• TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

The server has accepted `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` and presented it's certificates, which has has algorithm identifier `SHA512RSAEncryption`.

Does this mean the browser is able to verify SHA512 cert without any cipher suites in common?

Comment: related http://serverfault.com/questions/686170/windows-server-2008-r2-sha2-based-cipher-suites

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature algorithm used for the validation of the certificate (SHA-512 in your case) is independent from the algorithm used as the HMAC in the ciphers, i.e. for the encryption (SHA-256, SHA-384 in your case).